# Ember - Resize DIV on load, transition and resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, resize

I'm building an Ember app that needs to size a container DIV to be full window height on load of the application, and then run the same resize function again when transitioning to a new route, and then also on window resize.

On a normal site, I'd do this:

```
var appUI = {
    init: function(){
        appUI.sizeContainer();
    },

    sizeContainer: function(){
        var winHeight = jQuery(window).height();
        jQuery('#container').height(winHeight);
    },

    onResize: function() {
        appUI.sizeContainer();      
    }
}
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    appUI.init();

    jQuery(window).resize(function(){
        appUI.onResize();
    });
});
```

But obviously this won't work in Ember.

This can't be a component, because the `#container` DIV wraps the entire current view. But with Ember moving away from views, how should I do this?

The only way I came up with was to use a view, and hook onto `didInsertElement`, but I couldn't figure out how can I do it without having to create a view.js file for every route, that contains the same resize code? And how about the resize event? I thought the application view `didInsertElement` might work for this, but it only runs once on load.

All my route templates basically follow this patten:

```
{{top-header}}

{{background-image image=backgroundImage}}

{{side-menu session=session menuOpen=menuOpen}}

<div id="container" class="vert-center route-name"> 

    {{partial "_logo"}}         

    {{some-component}}

</div>
```

Comment: What is `livinUI`? If I understand you correctly, you want to call the `sizeContainer` function when the app loads, new route loads or window resizes? Will all your templates (for each route) be inside a `#container`, or does this id need to be set dynamically?

Comment: @nem I updated the question to show a template example. I fixed the typo with the var, it should have said `appUI`. And yes, I want a function to run on load, new route and resize (but maybe there is a more Ember way than than, I'd like to know). `#container` isn't dynamic, it's in every template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On loading the application and on `window` resize can be done pretty much the way you described.

One easy way is to override the [`renderTemplate`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate) hook inside the `ApplicationRoute`. Within this hook, you can render your application template and then initialize the `resize` listener on the `window` object:

```
// handles on document load and on window change events
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function(controller, model) {
        this.render('application');             // render the application template
        appUI.init();                           // call the init event on application load
        Ember.$(window).resize(function() {     // setup resize listener on the window object that will be called when window resizes
            appUI.onResize();
        });
    }
});
```

As far as resizing each time a route loads, you could implement a generic `Ember.Route`, let's call it `ResizableRoute` for example, that calls the `appUI.resize()` after its template is rendered. This can again be achieved with overriding the `renderTemplate` hook.

```
// calls onResize() each time the current route's template is rendered in the DOM
App.ResizableRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    renderTemplate: function() {
        // render the template with the same name as the route (assumes you follow ember naming conventions)
        this.render(this.routeName); 
        // call resize since the route is loaded         
        appUI.onResize();
    } 
});
```

Now you can make any other route extend this `ResizableRoute` and, every time that route's template is rendered, `appUI.onResize()` will be called.

```
App.AnyOtherRoute = App.ResizableRoute.extend({
    // do other stuff
});
```

The reason all the calls are made **AFTER** the template is rendered is because that way the `#container` element is definitely inserted in the DOM already and can be grabbed using jQuery.

#### Here is a running jsFiddle example

---

**EDIT**

Instead of overriding the `renderTemplate` hook, another way you could achieve this is to create a `ResizeUIComponent` that will perform resizing each time your route is loaded. The flaw is that you have to remember to insert this component into each route's template.

```
App.ResizeUIComponent = Ember.Component.extend({

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$().hide();   // make the component invisible, probably better to do it with css but this is a quick example
        appUI.onResize();
    }

});
```

And add this component to all templates (including application) you want to call `onResize()` each time they load:

```
{{top-header}}

{{background-image image=backgroundImage}}

{{side-menu session=session menuOpen=menuOpen}}

<div id="container" class="vert-center route-name"> 

    {{resize-ui}}  {{!-- add the invisible resize component as the child of #container to ensure necessary rendering order --}}    

    {{partial "_logo"}}         

    {{some-component}}

</div>
```

And you can add a listener on the `window` object after the `init` event of the `ApplicationController`:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    onInit: function() {
        Ember.$(window).resize(function() {     // setup resize listener on the window object that will be called when window resizes
            appUI.onResize();
        });
    }.on('init');
});
```

Comment: This looks interesting. How do you think it plays with the Ember 2.0 roadmap?  They are saying to stay away from `render()` here: https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97

Comment: Yes but in this case it is necessary. You need to wait for route's template to be rendered before you can grab the `#container` within it, so you have to override the `renderTemplate` hook and first render a template before resizing the UI. Essentially, you need to make sure the element is in the DOM **before** you try to grab it. As far as Ember 2.0, it says in the link that "*controller/template pair will eventually become a routable component.*" at which point you will be able to use `didInsertElement` of the component as the hook call after template is rendered.

Comment: The other way would be to use views, which is even more not future-proof for Ember 2.0...

Comment: Thanks @nem. I suspect views might be easier to port over to the new components in the future than this route based way render way. I also had a problem using `#container` (because IRL I'm using liquid fire, and have two `#container` in the DOM at one time.

Comment: this new component resizer could be better. I could just put it in my application.hbs file, or in index.html, so it's all in one place. But if that components `didInsertElement` hook is called, does it mean `container` is present? I thought components were super limited in their scope.

Comment: I just made a quick edit to make the component a child of `#container`. That way, `container` is definitely rendered when `didInsertElement` is called.